# pandas read_json from s3 with chunksize option returns single row multiple columns dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3

I have a json file in s3 (with >100 records), this is sample json file format:

```
[{
    "data": {
        "a": "hello"
    },
    "details": {
        "b": "hello1"
    },
    "dtype": "SP"
},
{
    "data": {
        "a": "hello2"
    },
    "details": {
        "b": "hello3"
    },
    "dtype": "SP"
}]
```

I use **aws wrangler** to read_json using boto3, I get the right format of dataframe.

```
         data          details      dtype
0   {'a': 'hello'}  {'b': 'hello1'}   SP
1  {'a': 'hello2'}  {'b': 'hello3'}   SP
```

If I use the ***chunksize*** option along with ***lines=True***, I get the dataframe in a single row, multiple column format.

```
                                                   0                                               1
0  {'data': {'a': 'hello'}, 'details': {'b': 'hel...    {'data': {'a': 'hello2'}, 'details': {'b': 'he...
```

Is there a way to still get right format of dataframe (multiple rows) with the size mentioned by ***chunksize***

Update: I have tried ***nrows*** instead of ***chunksize***. It didin't help, gives me the same output as ***chunksize***.

code I am using to read json file from s3:

```
import boto3
import botocore
import awswrangler as wr

client = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=s3_access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=s3_secret_key,
        region_name=s3_region,
    )

def read_json_s3(path, client, **args):
    try:
        return wr.s3.read_json(path=path, boto3_session=client, **args)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as err:
        raise err
```

I am sending `chunksize=1000, lines=True` as args

Comment: have you tried **nrows** instead of **chunksize** ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried nrows and it still gives me same output as chunksize.

Comment: Have you tried setting `lines` to `false` just to see what is returned?

Comment: try using orient='records' option